# Longlistselector

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to add highlighting effect to the item I select in longlistselector?
Also is it possible to implement multiple selection?

Answer (score 2):

You may find these two posts on WindowsPhoneGeek useful:

- [WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part1: Visual structure and API](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)
- [WP7 LongListSelector in depth | Part2: Data binding scenarios](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios)

You should be able to add a highlighting effect to the selected item by modifying the "Selected" state. I don't think the `LongListSelector` supports multiple selection.

Comment: Yes, but where part of the control should I add the selected state?

Comment: It would appear that the `LongListSelector` doesn't actually provide the notion of selection (presumably because as soon as you select something it closes). By the looks of things, I think you'd need to customize the classes to implement some visual states and to change state accordingly. It shouldn't be too difficult, though; there's already a `GroupSelected` event on the `LongListSelectoritemsControl`, which you could use to change the state for the groups.

Answer (score 2):

I found this, and it has all what I need.

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/01/a-windows-phone-7-jump-list-control/

Answer (score 0):

In the default implementation of LongListSelector you can not highlight the currently selected item. The only available VisualStates are:

```
* Scrolling
* NotScrolling
```

which are in the "ScrollStates" VisualStateGroup.

So actually there is no "Selected" state by default. Here is the code of available states:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```