# How to support multiple selections in a LongListSelector in Win Phone 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I want to add multiple selections in LongListSelector in my win phone8 app but i cant find a way to do that ?

1.is it even supported ?

2.if (1.) turns out to be 'NO' then how can this be achieved ?

( Win phone8 + XAML +C# )

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089368/longlistselector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `LongListMultiSelector` control from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)